# What are the column headings for eg RSGB live dx cluster?

Tags: dx, rsgb

The Web page for RSGB dx cluster doesn't have column headings. May be dumb question but what are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are asking about https://rsgb.org/main/operating/dx-cluster/.

Let's look at an example line:

2E0OBO  14030.5 SM5S    cw  13:10Z

This gives us from left to right: the callsign of the station making the spot (2E0OBO in the example); the frequency (14030.5 in the example); the callsign of the station being spotted (the "DX"; SM5S in the example); an optional comment by the spotter ("cw" in the example); and the time the spot was made (13:10 UTC in the example).

Comment: Helpful, thanks.